# Searching in in-memory DB in Angular

Tags: angular

I have an in-memory DB in angular

```
createDb(){
    let Data= [
      {id:1 , ProviderCode: '9W-', ProviderName: 'Jet Airways', ProviderType: 'Domestic' },
      {id:2 , ProviderCode: 'EK-', ProviderName: 'Emirates', ProviderType: 'International' },
    ];
    return {Data};
  }
```

and I have specified CRUD operations in separate service

```
 public getAllAirlines(){ 
       return this.httpClient.get(this.SERVER_URL + 'Data');
  }

  public getAirlines(ProviderType: String){
       return this.httpClient.get(`${this.SERVER_URL + 'Data'}/${ProviderType}`); 
  }
  public createAirlines(data: {ProviderCode: String, ProviderName: String, ProviderType: String}){
      return this.httpClient.post(`${this.SERVER_URL + 'Data'}`,data );
  }

  public deleteAirlines(AirlineId: String){
      return this.httpClient.delete(`${this.SERVER_URL + 'Data'}/${AirlineId}`);
  }
  public updateAirlines (data: {ProviderCode: String, ProviderName: String, ProviderType: String}) {
    return this.httpClient.put(`${this.SERVER_URL + 'Data'}/${data.ProviderCode}/${data.ProviderType}`, data);
  }
```

I have a Delete airline component, which has a form having details as ProviderCode and ProviderType to delete. To delete the record I need to retrieve the ID from the DB and I am unable to do that. Same case with update functionality. Please suggest me ways to do that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Let me know if my answer helps you with what you were looking for. Also, it is convention to start function params or any variables with small letters (e.g. getAirlines(providerType: String)). And classes with uppercase, however, typescripts number and string for example are exceptions to this. (e.g. getAirlines(providerType: string)). Not too important, but I thought I'd mention it. Just comment if you need more help.

Comment: Creating a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) can also help us better understand your code and improve the help we can give you.

Answer (score 0):

This function:

```js
getAllAirlines(){ 
  return this.httpClient.get(this.SERVER_URL + 'Data');
}
```

Will return you an observable.

In your component you can subscribe to it and that will get you all the Airline objects with their id.

Writing the function fullout might help you with understanding:

```js
getAllAirlines(): Observable<Airline[]>{ 
  return this.httpClient.get<Airline[]>(this.SERVER_URL + 'Data');
}
```

Let me also give an example of how to get the data from this request.

In your "delete-airline.component.ts":

```js
airlines: Airline[] = []
...
constructor(
  private separateService: SeparateService
) { }

ngOnInit():void {
  this.separateService.getAllAirlines().subscibe(
    data => this.airlines = data
  )
}
```

Then you can just loop over the items in your airlines array and use their id values...